# Korn Shell - nameref fails when not using positional arguments

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, ksh

As the title says, `nameref` (`typeset -n`) fails when not using positional arguments (ex: `$1`).

Version: sh (AT&T Research) 93u+m/1.0.0-beta.2 2021-12-17

Testing example:

```bash
function func_a {
    nameref ref=$1
    ref=( a=1 b=2 c=3 )
}

function func_b {
    typeset return_var=$1
    nameref ref=$return_var
    ref=( 1 2 3 )
}

# Success
function func_c1 {
    typeset var1
    func_a var1
    echo "var1.a = ${var1.a}"
}
func_c1

# Failure
function func_c2 {
    typeset var2
    func_b var2
    echo "var2[@] = ${var2[@]}"
}
func_c2
```

I'm expecting the same output. I need the change in variable name to stick to how arguments are parsed and checked in my functions.

Am I misunderstanding how `nameref` works?
Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1):

It may not have much to do with positional arguments, because if you run func_b a second time, it succeeds.

```
function func_a {
    nameref ref=$1
    ref=( a=1 b=2 c=3 )
}

function func_b {
    return_var=$1
    nameref ref=$return_var
    ref=( a=1 b=2 c=3 )
}

# Success
func_a var1
echo "var1.a = ${var1.a}"

# Failure
func_b var2
echo "var2.a = ${var2.a}"

# Success
func_b var2
echo "var2.a = ${var2.a}"
```

It may have more to do with compound variable `ref`, because if you assign a normal array, it succeeds.

```
function func_a {
    nameref ref=$1
    ref=( a=1 b=2 c=3 )
}

function func_b {
    return_var=$1
    nameref ref=$return_var
    ref=(1 2 3)
}

# Success
func_a var1
echo "var1.a = ${var1.a}"

# Success
func_b var2
echo "var2[@] = ${var2[@]}"
```

This is not a full answer to the question, but hopefully, it provides more material to investigate.

Comment: Indeed, it does but only in this case where i'm referencing a global variable. I've updated my question to stick a little more to my use case (nested function call that set a parent scope variable).